# How to show inheritance tree in Watch window during debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In a book when they type this in a Windows Forms application, it shows them inheritance tree:
[image]

I think in a book they use Visual Studio 2013. And I have Visual Studio 2019.

And here's what I get:
[image]

How to make Visual Studio show object graph as on the first screenshot?

Comment: You'd have to re-enable the old debugging engine, the one that was last used in VS2010.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".  I read somewhere, the memory is getting vague, that they made the new debugging engine flatten the view by popular demand.  A sensible demand btw.

Comment: Post it as an answer, I'll mark it as an answer, considering we can't transform the comment itself to an answer.

Comment: You don't need my help to complete the Q+A you started.  Just post what you discovered today and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans suggested in the comments to first post, I had to go in Tools > Options > Debugging > General, and tick the checkbox "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" to make object graphs as on the first screenshot.